# DataBase Design, Invitations and Events

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a project that i'm working on. It contains events and invitations to an event. Events can be public or private, each invitation has a statut (accepted,refused,pending)..I'm trying to figure out what db schema would be the best. Here is what I have right now, could youd advice me for what implementation shoud I continue with?

### 1. [image: List item]

2. [image: List item]

Obviously each table will contain more column...

In the first possibility, I would have a table for the Statut of the invitation : the statut would be accepted, refused or pending. The type of the event would be a boolean to tell if it's public or not.

In the secund possibility, I would have a table for the type of Event : the type would be a int (0 for private,1 for public) and the statut Invitation would be a int in the Invitations Table(0 for pending, 1 for accepted, 2 for pending)

A third possibility would be to mix the two previous solutions together.. I don't have anyone to ask the question to right now, so If one of you could tell me what implementation he would choose and why, it'd be very helpful, thank you !!

Comment: Each Event has one Invitation per User?

Comment: This is a matter of opinion... what are you comfortable coding in? What's the front end? PHP, .Net,? Sql Server, MySql, db2, etc. Licensing fees considered?

Comment: The frond end is in xamarin android, I have no problem with the language i'm coding in, licensing fees free if possible

Comment: I would say that neither of these look like a solid database design. But the top one is maybe closer. It seems like an invitation is for a specific person. Do you really need to have any number of status? That seems like a column in the invitation table to me. Unless you want to track when it was accepted and then later refused and again later pending. This question is both primarily opinion based and too broad.